# phtml file for checkout table

Tags: checkout, phtml, shipping-address, table

[image: checkout]

where do i find the phtml file for the picture above. i want to adjust the table itself. i actually know where the css is. i searched in already in /vendor/magento/module-costumer/view/frontend/
/app/design/frontend/.../magento-checkout

thank you

Answer (score 0):

All files you will find here:

*app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage*

Comment: i  use an template from templatemonster, so i dont have a base/default

Comment: This checkout/onepage folder will be present in this templatemonster theme.

Comment: Or you can enable template path hint option in Magento.

Comment: in app/..../checkout i dont have a onepage

Comment: its only in vendor/.../checkout and i already enabled the template path. he shows me the vendor directory but there isnt the table at all.